# undefined method `__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround'

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am getting the below error in fresh react-native installation and when trying to do pod install.

```html
[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

undefined method `__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00000001068fad98 @defined_in_file=#<Pathname:/Users/fullmad/Projects/saga-reserve/sagaMobile/ios/Podfile>, @internal_hash={}, @root_target_definitions=[#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition label=Pods>], @current_target_definition=#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition label=Pods>, @post_install_callback=#<Proc:0x000000012a01a6a0 /Users/fullmad/Projects/saga-reserve/sagaMobile/ios/Podfile:26>, @installation_options=#<Pod::Installer::InstallationOptions:0x00000001068b6148 @clean=true, @deduplicate_targets=true, @deterministic_uuids=true, @integrate_targets=true, @lock_pod_sources=true, @warn_for_multiple_pod_sources=true, @warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo=true, @share_schemes_for_development_pods=false, @disable_input_output_paths=false, @preserve_pod_file_structure=false, @generate_multiple_pod_projects=false, @incremental_installation=false, @skip_pods_project_generation=false>>

/Users/fullmad/Projects/saga-reserve/sagaMobile/ios/Podfile:28:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:196:in `post_install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:945:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:933:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:932:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:331:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in `write!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:330:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:309:in `create_and_save_projects'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:301:in `generate_pods_project'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:180:in `integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:167:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using M1 based computer, you can still comment "__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)" line in your Podfile and run the command `arch -x86_64 pod install` instead of `pod install`.

[Better Support for Apple Silicon, Xcode 13, and iOS](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/10/01/version-066#better-support-for-apple-silicon-xcode-13-and-ios-15)

Comment: what does this do exactly?

installs the pods relevant to the intel x86 architecture? how does that help?

Answer (score 7):

If You don't use M1 based computer to build, You can comment "__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)" line in Your Podfile.

Comment: so if I'm getting this right, the podifle that the RN upgrade tools generate for you breaks your builds if you're not on M1 by default? Are they serious?

Answer (score 6):

Check `ios/Podfile` syntax and that our `__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround` Ruby method's defined (might be worth `rm -rf node_modules && yarn` in case)

[image: __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround]

```rb
# node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb

# ...

def __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
      end
  end

  `sed -i -e  $'s/__IPHONE_10_0/__IPHONE_12_0/' Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h`
end
```

Here's a minimal [template](https://github.com/leotm/react-native-template-typescript) to check out the [Podfile](https://github.com/leotm/react-native-template-typescript/blob/master/ios/Podfile)

Answer (score 6):

This method has been removed in React Native v0.73.0, [see this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/0ab8b40fd64ad86b4598293faa0b77e71fc9d349)

You probably don't need this post install phase anymore and can safely remove this line in your Podfile :
`__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)`

Answer (score 4):

To conditionally apply the workaround for **M1 Macs**, follow these steps:

```
post_install do |installer|
....
  if installer.respond_to?(:__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround)
    installer.__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround
  end
....
end
```

- The code checks if the installer object has the method __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround, indicating compatibility with M1 Macs.
- If compatible, it calls the method to apply the workaround.
- Otherwise, it skips the workaround, preventing errors on non-M1 devices.

Comment: it helps. It is in file ios/Podfile